# Access child item of currently selected DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<a class="category-tag-item category-item inactive" id="someId">
    <span class="category-name">Category Name</span>
    <span class="toggle">Inactive</span>
</a>
```

My JQuery:

```
$(".category-item").bind("click", function () {

    // How to access the span element with id="toggle"?

});
```

The comment in the script pretty much covers it. After having access to the `<a>` tag in the JQuery with the `$(this)` reference, how do I access it's child element, the `<span>` element with `id="toggle"` ?

Comment: `id="toggle"` or `class="toggle"` ?

Comment: How about `$(this).find('.toggle')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".category-item").bind("click", function (event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).find('.toggle').html("clicked");
});
```

Comment: Upvoted, although I'd use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.currentTarget)` for clarity and brevity :)